# Return false to invoking method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following class and want the steps to return `false` when it arrives at `step_two`:

```
class Something

  def steps
    step_one
    step_two
    step_three
  end

  private

    def step_one
      some_function
    end

    def step_two
      if some_other_function
        return false
      end
      true
    end

    def step_three
      some_function
    end

end
```

As this is written, the `steps` method will not stop execution at `step_two` and will proceed to `step_three`. I can write it in this way to make it work:

```
def steps
  step_one
  return false unless step_two
  step_three
end
```

Or if all three steps could return false:

```
def steps
  return false unless step_one
  return false unless step_two
  return false unless step_three
end
```

Is there a better way to do this? I guess I'm asking if an invoking method in Ruby can return false if an invoked method returns false?

Comment: After re-reading the post, I'm not sure if I'm understanding the question. You said you *want the steps method to return false when it hits step_two*. What do you mean by "hits"?

Comment: -1 because you've seen @Paul's question and didn't answer it. Please edit the first sentence to replace "hits" with something that explains what you want to achieve.

Comment: Brutal. Guess a guy can't get lunch. By hits, I mean "arrives at". After step_one is finished. It "arrives at" step two. I've also changed if to unless so this makes sense. That was a typo.

Comment: @psrabbit Then why bother having `step_three` in the method? If you want the method to exit and return after `step_one` or `step_two` is finished, either put an unconditional return statement after that line, or simply remove everything else after that line.

Comment: @psrabbit The confusion (at least mine) is stemming from the "hits" / "arrived at" requirement, which seems to contradict your last statement in the question. If I understand the last statement correctly, yes, you can return early programmatically with the `unless`, or the `!` operator. If `step_two` returns true, then the return is skipped, and `step_three` is executed (and returned implicitly). Is that the desired behaviour?

Comment: Sorry I wrote a terrible example. I've updated it again to reflect the fact that step_two can return either true or false. If it is true, the steps method should proceed to step_three. Like a guard clause, step_two should prevent anything else from happening in the steps method if it is false, and the steps method itself should return false if anything inside of it returns false.

Comment: @psrabbit Ok, I get it now. Check out my update. Let me know if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Yep! Someone else gave a similar answer earlier but it was down-voted for some reason. Thanks for confirming.

Comment: @psrabbit Yeah, its possible kroky understood before the clarification, which is fine. The downvoter probably incorrectly thought as most of us did and believed it was a wrong answer. I've given him an upvote, and I think you have enough rep to do the same if you like. Also, the only difference between `and` and `&&` is the order precedent, so feel free to use either (just be aware of the precedence. I prefer to use `&&`, partly out of habit, and that it has a higher order which is usually preferable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your method `step_two` is returning false, the issue is because your `if` statement is resolving to false, and happily proceeds to `step_three`. You have a couple of options:

Use the `unless` operator instead of `if`, like so:

```
def steps
  step_one
  return false unless step_two
  step_three
end
```

or you can use the `!` (not) operator:

```
def steps
  step_one
  return false if !step_two
  step_three
end
```

**Update**

From the clarification in the comments, you want your `step` method to return false if any of the other method calls return false, or true if everything returned true. Practically speaking, something like this:

```
def steps
  step_one && step_two && step_three
end
```

In this case, if any of the methods return false, because we are using `&&` (and) operators, the whole thing fails, and you receive a false value. For example, if `step_one` returns true, and `step_two` returns false, `step_three` is never run and the value of the whole operation is resolved to false.

Comment: I had if but it should have been unless as you said. Made the change above.

Answer (score 2):

You can chain method invocation and conditionally execute further steps only if previous return true like this:

```
def steps
  step_one and step_two and step_three
end
```

This way, `steps` method will also return true or false based on the overall execution of each step - i.e. true will mean all steps were executed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

What about?

```
def steps
  step_one
  if step_two
      step_three
  end
end
```

Is this better to you?

Comment: That doesn't seem much better to me. If I wanted the steps method to return false for any of the three, this would get quite complicated.